# RestSharp JSON Serializating C#

Tags: json, restsharp

This is my class:

```
   public class skus
    {
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public OptionValue options { get; set; }
    }
    public class OptionValue
    {
        public int product_option_id { get; set; }
        public int option_value_id { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is JSON serialization:

```
 request.AddBody(new skus
 {

   sku = "9914123456123",
   options = new OptionValue
       { product_option_id = 1,                              
         option_value_id = 2071
       }
 });
```

This generates JSON data like this:

> {"sku":"9914123456123","options":{"product_option_id":1,"option_value_id":2071}}

I want it like this:

{"sku":"9914123456123","options":**[**{"product_option_id":1,"option_value_id":2071}**]**}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON and JavaScript, `[]` denotes an array, so your object must have an array or list in C#:

```
public class skus
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public OptionValue[] options { get; set; } // <-- modified to be an array
}

public class OptionValue
{
    public int product_option_id { get; set; }
    public int option_value_id { get; set; }
}
```

And your code should be:

```
request.AddBody(new skus
    {
        sku = "9914123456123",
        options = new[]       // <-- modified to initialize an array with one object
        {
            new OptionValue
            {
                product_option_id = 1,                              
                option_value_id = 2071
            }
        }
     });
```